# emoji no PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x

estou utilizando o pycharm, já baixei o modulo emoji e, mesmo assim aparece essa mensagem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aspire/Desktop/curso-de-py-gua/aula08.modulos/ex.gua/emoji.py", line 1, in <module>
    import emoji
  File "C:\Users\Aspire\Desktop\curso-de-py-gua\aula08.modulos\ex.gua\emoji.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(emoji.emojize('olá mundo :punch:',use_aliases=True))
AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'emojize'
```

O código:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('olá mundo :punch:',use_aliases=True))
```

Comment: O teu script principal também se chama `emoji.py`?

Answer (score 2):

Eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que você nomeou o seu script principal com o mesmo nome da lib `emoji`, então na hora do `import emoji` ele acaba importando o script principal ao invés da classe da lib.

Troque o nome do seu script principal de `emoji.py` para algo como `app.py` e teste novamente.

Comment: nossa foi por causa disso, agr deu outro problema que é, o emoji aparece preto ao invés de amarelo mas, muito obrigado.

Comment: @lucas vou testar, mas é possivel que seja por causa do seu windows, não tem suporte para emojis coloridos, poderia marcar as resposta como correta? Se não souber como veja os detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: sim sim, valeu, ajudou muito

Comment: @lucas marque a resposta como correta por favor, se não souber como veja este tutorial: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: Valeu!! Essa e a solução, também estava com esse problema.

Answer (score -3):

Também sou iniciante e estava procurando solução para esse problema.
Percebi que o módulo estava com o nome "django-emoji" e não "emoji".

Consegui resolver indo nas configurações do Pycharm. File > Settings > Project:pythonProject > Python Interpreter. Primeiro cliquei no módulo "django-emoji" e depois cliquei no sinal de menos "-" para desinstalar. Depois cliquei no sinal de mais e pesquisei por "emoji" e instalei o módulo "emoji" por lá.

No meu caso, acho que havia instalado o módulo errado.

Possoal veterano, se eu estiver falando besteira me avise! ;)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).